# SDL Tridion License Agreement?

Tags: 2011, 2013, 2009

Where can I find the license agreement Or Legal Agreements for SDL Tridion,

I came across the [Legal Notice](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-C4B1152A-622C-441C-B06F-3D839CE0132F) available at SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 documentation,

This is the only documentation available? anything else we need to consider?

Answer (score 4):

As SDL Tridion is an enterprise piece of software, licence agreements (and costings) are usually negotiated on a per-customer basis.

The customer should have a copy of your license agreement from SDL, or you could contact your SDL account manager.

License restrictions often include, but are not limited to:

1. Number of website Publications available
2. Number of servers that the software can be deployed to
3. Number of CPUs per machine
4. Number of Content Manager users
5. Accompanying products available (Audience Manager, Outbound email, SDL Mobile, etc.)

As this is proprietary software, you can probably assume that no part of the product should be shared outside of your company, and that the code should not be de-compiled or shared.

Answer (score 3):

You should contact your company's procurement department or partner manager to see what agreement you have with SDL.

Typically every partner or client will have a different set of terms and features.